Converting from UTM to GCS in ArcGIS Pro
I'm trying to display point data over a basemap with a different CRS.
Basemap CRS =
Projected Coordinate System: NAD 1983 UTM Zone 15N | Geographic Coordinate System: NAD 1983
Point data CRS =
Projected Coordinate System: WGS 1984 | Geographic Coordinate System: WGS 1984
Can someone explain a good way to convert my point data layers to the same CRS as my basemap?

Not surprisingly, the Project command is used to project data. Of course, "project-on-the fly" has been a thing for decades now, so projecting data isn't completely necessary.

When I try to use the project command, I get the following error:
Warning 001839 "A datum transformation is expected, but the parameter is empty."
Having trouble understanding what this means.
